# How to fix render-blocking javascript and css in above-the-fold content

Tags: google-pagespeed

When i am testing my website in google insights it shows "Eliminate render-blocking javascript and css in above-the-fold content". I am not using Wordpress..
Plese help me...

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate render-blocking javascript css 
What helped us with the js was   async
 
We have 3 js scripts it only worked on 2 the other one async stopped the menue  from working The CSS you can min or we found taking out links to google fonts
and maps The fonts and maps are good but they come at a cost to loading your site.
If its speed you want on your website look at your html code this has the biggest effect in the speed of your site  johnc